# Trigger collider only if touchphase ended

Tags: unity-game-engine

Anyone please help, I'm new to unity and currently making a mobile garbage segregation game where players must drag falling garbage into its respective trash bin.

The game has "4 trash bins" and each have its own polygon collider which is set into a trigger. Currently, the triggers destroy "garbage gameobjects" that are dragged onto it as soon as the colliders of the trashbin and the garbage collided with their edges, I'm using "OnTriggerEnter2D" to perform the destroy function.

However, what I want was the triggers to destroy the garbage gameobjects "only IF the player stopped touching the garbage and dropped it on the place of the trigger"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OnTriggerEnter(Collider)` and `OnTriggerExit(Collider)` to change the state of your garbage.
In this way a bool should be sufficient(in trash/not in trash).

So:

your garbage script:

```
bool inTrash=false;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        inTrash=true;
    }

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        inTrash=false;
    }
```

your touch controller script:

```
//your touch management here
case TouchPhase.Ended:
                   if(garbage.inTrash)
                   {
                     garbage.Destroy();
                   }
                    break;
```

Another aproach: use OnTriggerStay(Collider)

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
//OnTriggerStay is called once per physics update for every Collider other that is touching the trigger.
        if (yourTouch.TouchPhase==TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            DestroyGarbage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mr. Victor your answer works great,  its just that i forgot to mention that the garbage was a prefab and I am spawning plenty of those in the game. The problem now was, the other prefabs are also changing the value of "inTrash" variable as they enter and exit the trigger

Comment: If i understood your problem, all your prefabs now are in state "in trash"/"not in trash" when only one of them is inside/ouside trash. If this is your problem now:
you should have: 
1 script for your InputManager
1 script for garbage with triggers to attach to your prefab/prefabs
in this way you will have 1 InTrash bool for each instance of your garbage in scene.

Comment: Could you give some example on how can i implement your suggestion Mr. Victor